# Linq-to-SQL weird error

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to Linq-to-SQL. So I learn it using some youtube tutorials.
I start a new project (asp.net mvc), add a new data (linq) named 'test'.
In my controllers I type `testDataContext db = new testDataContext()`
And it works.

So here comes the problem. I'm working on the other project (asp.net mvc), where I have more controllers and more everything. When I add a new linq the it doesn't find it in project.

And I do it exactly the same way (testDataContext ...).

I have Linq library included.

Anyone knows whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: is your asp.net mvc project referencing the project which contains the daatacontext?

Comment: is this simply a namespace issue? i.e. do you have the necessary `using` directives?

Comment: its in the same project. I did the same thing with a new project (and i can do it 100 times again), and its going to work, but it doesn't work in this project
-----------------------------------
i have 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

Comment: Let me see the top lines of both files; the LINQ file and the file trying to acess the LINQ. I need every line including the namespace line, but not the lines below

Comment: Ok, problem solved. The program made me a wierd namespace in .cs (linq file)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `using System.Data.Linq;`

Comment: Read the question again... "I have Linq library included."

Comment: @Jannis - read his using statements in the comments, this one isn't included.